# Setting version column in append only table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

We have a table that will store versions of records.

The columns are:

```
Id (Guid)
VersionNumber (int)
Title (nvarchar)
Description (nvarchar)
etc...
```

Saving an item will insert a new row into the table with the same Id and an incremented VersionNumber.

I am not sure how is best to generate the sequential VersionNumber values. My initial thought is to:

```
SELECT @NewVersionNumber = MAX(VersionNumber) + 1
FROM VersionTable
WHERE Id = @ObjectId
```

And then use the the @NewVersionNumber in my insert statement.

If I use this method do I need set my transaction as serializable to avoid concurrency issues? I don't want to end up with duplicate VersionNumbers for the same Id.

Is there a better way to do this that doesn't make me use serializable transactions?

Comment: @Brownie - There isn't a clear response to my question about the safety of my answer yet, I'm going to sleep on it and then check back - possible delete my answer (I'd hate to lead you astray). There is some nice info there, particularly about methods like table hints that could make your query safe. Still, using a constraint is probably your simplest and safest bet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to avoid concurrency issues (or in your specific case duplicate inserts) you could create a Compound Key as the Primary Key for your table, consisting of the ID and VersionNumber columns. This would then enforce a unique constraint on the key column.

Subsequently your insert routine/logic can be devised to handle or rather CATCH an insert error due to a duplicate key and then simply re-issue the insert process.

It may also be worth mentioning that unless you specifically need to use a GUID i.e. because of working with SQL Server Replication or multiple data sources, that you should consider using an alternative data type such as BIGINT.

Comment: So that will mean I get an exception back if it fails and almost no extra cost if it succeeds. Awesome.

Unfortunately in this case it needs to be a Guid.

Answer (score 2):

I had thought that the following single insert statement would avoid concurrency issues, but after Heinzi's excellent answer to [my question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994771/is-and-insert-with-a-select-statement-safe-for-concurrency) it turns out that this is not safe at all:

```
Insert Into VersionTable
(Id, VersionNumber, Title, Description, ...)
Select @ObjectId, max(VersionNumber) + 1, @Title, @Description
From VersionTable
Where Id = @ObjectId
```

I'm leaving it just for reference. Of course this would work with either table hints or a transaction isolation level of Serializable, but overall the best solution is to use a constraint.

Comment: +1. "Putting stuff in a single SQL statement solves concurrency problems" is a common misconception, so it's good to have your answer here as a reference.