# How to increment Registration number using ado.net?

Tags: sql-server, ado.net

I am inserting student values to a table using ado.net form.I want to generate registration number automatically.
For Example, "R0001"

Everytime  it will automatically incremened by 1.

- "R0001" -> "R0002-> "R0003" and so on.
- "R0010" -> "R0011" and so on.
- "R0100" -> "R0101" and so on.

But i am unable to generate registration number automatically.
    Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please read about http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work

Answer (score 0):

I would have

- an `ID INT IDENTITY` column - it's automatically incremented by SQL Server
- add a computed, persisted column

  ```
  ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable
     ADD RegistrationNumber AS 'R' + RIGHT('0000' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(4)), 4) PERSISTED
  ```

The table will contain values `1, 2, 3, 4` for the `ID` column, and R0001, R0002, R0003, `R0004` for the `RegistrationNumber` column

Answer (score 0):

One option:

- Use an IDENTITY value so you get 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 etc

Then do one of:

- Add the R and leading zeroes in the client code
- Use a [computed column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250.aspx) on the table

Like

```
CREATE TABLE Students (
    StudentID int NOT NULL IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    StudentName
    ... ,
    RegistrationNumber AS 'R' + RIGHT('0000' + CAST(StudentID AS varchar(5)), 5)
```

There is no *elegant and clean* way to generate one columns R0001, R0002 etc. And you'll get gaps too for failed INSERTs.

You can make the RegistrationNumber column unique too

Comment: CREATE TABLE Students (
    StudentID int NOT NULL IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Name varchar(20),
 Course Varchar(20),
    RegistrationNumber AS 'R' + RIGHT('0000' + CAST(StudentID AS varchar(5)), 5)) How to insert values?

Comment: But how to insert values in this table?

Comment: @Sonu Kumar: INSERT (Name, Course) only. SQL Server will manage StudentID  and RegistrationNumber

Comment: @Sonu Kumar: please accept and/or upvote then (the tick and up arrow on the left of my answer). See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to otherwise sort the existing fields based upon some id/timestamp, you can simply get the latest entry, remove the r, increment, and save the value.

```
DECLARE @RegNum INT, @RegNumChar VARCHAR(5)
SET @RegNum = CAST(SUBSTRING(RegistrationNumber, 2, LEN(RegistrationNumber)) AS INT)
SET @RegNum = @RegNum + 1
SET @RegNumChar = 'R" + CONVERT(varchar(5), @RegNum)
```

Comment: If you mean a manual identity type action, this isn't safe for concurrency. Two processes can easily get the same number.

Comment: Here's how to make such manual solutions safe for concurrency: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994771/in-tsql-is-an-insert-with-a-select-statement-safe-in-terms-of-concurrency/1994922#1994922