# Duplicate value insertion, when using isolation level serializable

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table `SalesOrders`, which holds the `salesOrder` for a particular `organization`. Because I track invoices across many organizations, the table also contains an `invoice`. Per-organization, the `salesOrder` should increment by one, without gaps.

I need to do a

```
INSERT INTO SalesOrders (...) 
VALUES (...
, SELECT MAX(salesOrder) + 1 
    FROM SalesOrders 
    WHERE organization = @org)
```

But this [isn't safe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1994922/1084945) without `ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE` or equivalent locks.

However, when I wrap within a transaction with that isolation level, I'm seeing duplicate values inserted into my table. I don't understand why: the transaction isolation level should prevent this?

The block of code I'm using (PHP PDO) is below.

What reasons could there be for me to see duplicate `salesNumbers` in my table, as a result of this query?

---

```
$db->query('SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE');

$db->beginTransaction();
$query = '
    SELECT  MAX(orderNumber) AS number
    FROM    SalesOrders
    WHERE   organization = :organization';

$params = array(':organization' => $organizationId);

$statement = $db->prepare($query);
$statement->execute($params);

// Sometimes we have no results at all [no sales for a particular organization]
$existing = $statement->fetchAll();
$newNumber = (sizeof($existing) == 1 ? $existing[0]['number'] + 1 : 1);

$createQuery = 'INSERT INTO SalesOrders (
                    organization,
                    orderNumber,
                    invoice
                ) VALUES (
                    :organization,
                    :number,
                    :invoice
                )';
$createParams = array(
    ':organization' => $organizationId,
    ':number' => $newNumber,
    ':invoice' => $invoiceId
);

$secondStatement = $db->prepare($createQuery);
$secondStatement->execute($createParams);

$db->commit();
```

---

More information:

The table in question has ~4300 rows, with 11 duplicated values. For example:

```
id      organization    invoice salesOrderNumber
12830   43              12975   705
12831   43              12976   705
```

Comment: Here's the scenario that fails: 1) first client executes the `SELECT`. 2) second client executes the `SELECT`. (This is not blocked by the first client even under `SERIALIZABLE`, since the `SELECT`s are compatible and both take shared locks.) 3) first client performs `INSERT` and commits (locks taken by the `INSERT` are released). 4) second client performs `INSERT` and commits. To fix this, use `WITH (HOLDLOCK)` or `WITH (SERIALIZABLE)` as a table hint in the first `SELECT` (and then putting the whole transaction under `SERIALIZABLE` is optional).

Comment: @JeroenMostert: Isn't that the situation where a deadlock occurs? After `T1` and `T2` have finished their `SELECT`, they both have S-locks on the table. `T1` can't perform an `INSERT` (requiring the raising of an `X-lock`) whilst `T2` maintains it's `S-lock` on the table (thus [deadlock](https://pablocastilla.wordpress.com/2012/01/19/deadlocks-in-serializable-transactions-with-sql-server/)). This is the basis of my question: two transactions interleaving as you've described _should deadlock_, because otherwise they violate 'serializability', do they not?

Comment: Locks are usually as granular as possible, so we're actually taking row locks and range locks rather than table locks (otherwise an `INSERT` would be blocked if even one single `SELECT` was active in a transaction somewhere). To be honest, I'm not clear on the kinds of locks the first `SELECT` takes. It should range lock on `organization = :organization`, and then, as you rightly say, any `INSERT` on another session for that organization should block. (This is not a deadlock situation since it's waiting for the same lock to upgrade.)

Comment: Try inserting a sleep/break after the `SELECT` (or just replay the statements in Management Studio) and use `sp_lock` to get a list of what's being locked, and whether or not the `INSERT` is blocked. I find my ability to reason about locking is quickly overwhelmed, and actually observing them works better.